# Seperating two functions using Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to bind two different functions to two different parts of the treeview. the command `deleteItem` should only apply to rows, whilst the `columnselect` function should only apply to columns. When I run this code the second bind overrides the first.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.font import Font
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import ttk

def deleteItem(a):
    print("In delete Item")
    curItem = AttendanceView.focus()
    inter_var = AttendanceView.item(curItem)
    ListValues = inter_var['values']
    print(ListValues)

def columnnameselect(q):
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("","You didn't press a row")
# AttendanceView Specific Table Components
Attendance=tk.Tk()
AttendanceView = ttk.Treeview(Attendance)
AttendanceView["columns"] = ("firstname", "secondname","patrol","present")
AttendanceView.grid(row=3, column=1)
AttendanceView.heading("#0", text="", anchor="w")
AttendanceView.column("#0", anchor="center", width=5, stretch=tk.NO)
AttendanceView.heading("firstname", text="First Name", anchor="w")
AttendanceView.column("firstname", anchor="center", width=80)
AttendanceView.heading("secondname", text="Second Name", anchor="w")
AttendanceView.column("secondname", anchor="center", width=90)
AttendanceView.heading("patrol", text="Patrol", anchor="w")
AttendanceView.column("patrol", anchor="center", width=80)
AttendanceView.heading("present", text="Present", anchor="w")
AttendanceView.column("present", anchor="center", width=80)
AttendanceView.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=5)
AttendanceView.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', deleteItem)
AttendanceView.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', columnnameselect)
AttendanceViewScrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(Attendance, orient="vertical", command=AttendanceView.yview)
AttendanceView.configure(yscroll=AttendanceViewScrollbar.set)
AttendanceViewScrollbar.grid(row=3, column=6, sticky="ns")


AttendanceView.insert("", "end", text="", values=(("Ethel",("Kennedy"),("Cow"),(""))))
AttendanceView.insert("", "end", text="", values=(("Jack",("Kennedy"),("Lion"),(""))))
AttendanceView.insert("", "end", text="", values=(("Bobby",("Kennedy"),("Zebra"),(""))))
```

The desired outcome:

- When a column is selected, `columnselect` is run.
- When a row is selected, `deleteItem` is run.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do exactly , but check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.identify (and related functions like identify_column...). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584415/how-to-bind-an-action-to-the-heading-of-a-tkinter-treeview-in-python

Comment: @Mekanik Its hard to put this in words. Im looking for a solution such as `AttendaceView['headers'].bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', columnselect)`