# Python ttkwidget Table how to bind event when column width is changed

Tags: python, ttkwidgets

Looking for a method to get an event when one changes the width of a column
Eg. I would like to have an event when the column width (A or B) is changed by user interaction. My example only binds when the full table width is changed

```
from ttkwidgets import Table
import tkinter as tk
    
def changed(event):
    print(event)
    
root = tk.Tk()

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

columns = ["A", "B"]
table = Table(root, columns=columns)
table.bind('<Configure>',  changed)

for col in columns:
    table.heading(col, text=col)
    table.column(col, width=100, stretch=False)


for i in range(3):
    table.insert('', 'end', iid=i,
                 values=(i, i) + tuple(i + 10 * j for j in range(2, 7)))

# add scrollbars
sx = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal', command=table.xview)
sy = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical', command=table.yview)
table.configure(yscrollcommand=sy.set, xscrollcommand=sx.set)

table.grid(sticky='nesw')
sx.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
sy.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
root.update_idletasks()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid()
root.geometry('400x200')

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with link
[How to bind an action to the heading of a tkinter treeview in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584415/how-to-bind-an-action-to-the-heading-of-a-tkinter-treeview-in-python)

So I did:

```
table.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_button_release_1)
```

and implemented:

```
def on_button_release_1(event):
    region = table.identify("region", event.x, event.y)
    if region == "separator":
        print(event)
```